# Room - how to return a new custom type from query that selects String and Int?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have the following query function -

```kotlin
 @Query("select chats.groupId, (select count(*) from ${Constants.messagesTable} where groupId = chats.groupId) as 'count' from ${Constants.chatsTable} chats where chats.groupId in (:groupIdListAsString)")
    fun getChatMessagesCount(groupIdListAsString : String) : LiveData<List<ChatCountModel>>
```

and the following object -

```kotlin
@Dao
data class ChatCountModel (val groupId : String, val count : Int)
```

I have checked the query, it is working fine. But it can't create the needed custom object from the 2 selections I make from this query.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Hi I think the data class will not have the @Dao annotation

Comment: Please clarify - what do you mean by "it can't create the needed custom object"? You've got some error message? Or null-value?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - `groupIdListAsString` was a list joined to string. I just gave it the list and it was able to work with it as a list object.